# Mojolicious, morbo command not found

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I've installed Mojolicious on OS X Mavericks using the instructions found on the Mojolicious web page (http://mojolicio.us/).

The directions state " To run this example with the built-in development web server just put the code into a file and start it with "morbo". " When I do so, the command line gives me the error " morbo: command not found ".

I'll delete this if it's some rookie mistake but the only solution I've found is another stackoverflow page that didn't help me.

Comment: Which installation instructions did you use specifically?  I'd add that to your question.

Answer (score 3):

As part of the installation process of any Perl module that contains scripts, they are installed to a specific location. If that location is not in your executable path, then they cannot be run. I would do a file search for the `morbo` script and check your `$PATH` variable. The script must be in the directories listed in that variable to run it by name. Check by running `echo $PATH` in a terminal (I know that works on Linux, I think it should work for Mac).

You can also run morbo by executing the full path to the executable:

```
/home/joel/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.18.1/bin/morbo myapp.pl
```

(p.s. as you can see, I use [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/), I highly recommend it).

Answer (score 2):

My morbo is here: /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.24.0_1/bin/morbo

if I run it from there it works as expected. Just run

find / -name morbo and you will find it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but with the standard Perl install, not perlbrew. I was expecting the `mojo` command to be available, but I only had the `morbo` command.

```
which morbo -> /opt/local/bin/morbo
sudo ln -s /opt/local/bin/morbo /opt/local/bin/mojo
```